# Android Studio's phone emulator cannot read your local file system: URL.openStream throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

For an Android app, I was trying to read a file into a string via URL.openStream. In the future, this will be a remote URL, but for now, I'm thought I'd try testing with a local file. I was pretty sure the URL was correct because when I cut&paste the URL into Chrome it displays the file nicely. The screenshot shows the values of the variables and the Chrome display of the file:

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio with variables and Chrome displaying the file]

```
static private String readFromURL( String urlstr )
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        URL url = new URL( urlstr );
        InputStream strm = url.openStream();
        InputStreamReader rdr = new InputStreamReader( strm );
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( rdr );
        String line;
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null )
            sb.append( line );
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
        { return "Error during read from server: " + ex.toString(); }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Alas, I completely forgot something ...

Comment: Why are you using a URL when you can use a FileInputStream?

Comment: 1) This is nothing to do with android studio, so I have retagged it as Android.  2) Please explain how you are executing this code.  Is it part of an Android app?  Plain Java code?  3) Please don't send us code as screenshots: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart I'm reading from URLStream because that's what it will be as soon as I have it working on this much simpler case. As you can see I'm using the file:/// URL-style, and Chrome accepts that happily.

Comment: @StephenC Plain Java, made in Android Studio. Executing as an app using a phone simulator. Running with the 'debug' icon. It throws at the `openStream` call. I was hoping this was not very relevant, but stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

OMG I just realized that the phone emulator has no access to my local file systems. Which means that I cannot do a 'simple' test like that, the data always has to be got from a real URL on the Internet.

Or I'd have to copy some data to the phone emulator when it starts, but that would make things unnecessarily complicated.